# jQuery one liner for finding and highlighting rows where contents of 1st cell is gte 2nd cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

```
$('tr').find(need help here).parent().css('backgroundColor', '#fcc');
```

Would like to perform inequality check of two dates (both strings) in the 'need help here' section of the above snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not one liner but you can put on one line if you want ;)

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    if(new Date($(this).find('td').first().html()) == new Date($(this).find('td').eq(2).html())){
       $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#fcc'));
    }
})
```

Comment: Gregoire == ninja returns true!